# Xcode : Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I was. trying to learn flutter and have bought macbook for that, and this is the first time i am using macbook, so please explain thoroughly about what should I do.
below is the dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Text('hello'), ); 
  }
}
```

I have downloaded all the necessary softwares, but still I am geting the following error:

```
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/pratteekshaurya/Desktop/flutterApp/may19/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
    Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).
Exited (sigterm)
```

Please help me in resolving this issue